# How can i import train_test_split to pyinstaller executable file?

Tags: python, tkinter, scikit-learn, pyinstaller

Hi everyone i had some problems, but while i am solving them new ones are coming. For example after i have converted the py file to exe file i was getting No module named "numpy.random.common" error so i solved this with --hidden-import = "...". In my program i am using train_test_split library to split the data to train and test sets. When i open the exe file i can not do this so i recognized that in the dist file there is a sklearn file but in the sklearn file there is no model_selection file so i think my problem is that,how can i import the sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split to pyinstaller exe ? I have tried --hidden-import="sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split" but it didn't work. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution,
I have defined from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split in the def ..(): 
then i have removed it, and write on the top of the main code. When i convert the py file it gave me an error like :

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.neighbors.ball_tree.NeighborsHeap'
```

i write it like --hidden-import="sklearn.neighbors.ball_tree.NeighborsHeap" so it is solved.